# Take Persistable URI Permission for ACTION_SEND intent filter uri results in SecurityException

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-jetpack-compose, android-context

My users can select files via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`

```kotlin
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument(),
    onResult = onResult
)
```

After which I use `takePersistableUriPermission`

```kotlin
contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

This works great! Now the picker UI is not what I'd call optimal, so I want to also allow inverting the control flow by sharing the file with my app.

```xml
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

And in `onCreate` or `onNewIntent` in my `Activity`, I want to also take the persistable URI permission.

```kotlin
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    // null checks etc
    val uri = intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) as? Uri ?: return
    contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    // ...
}
```

This however, results in a SecurityException:

> java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10146 and Uri content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/61/REQUIRE_ORIGINAL/NONE/image/jpeg/702648108

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you take persistable permission?  I think it is not offered to your app to begin with. Did you check the flags if they were there in the received intent?

Comment: `contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);` That is not the way to do it. Please look at examples. First look in the offered flags if that flag is there.

Comment: I have to get long-term access to the file to display it inside my app. I don't want to necessarily copy it into my apps internal storage, if I can avoid it.
` I think it is not offered you to begin with`, yes that is the problem. Can I request that a) after receiving the URI or b) before receiving the URI?

Comment: No you cannot request that.

Comment: Wow, that's unfortunate..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve this?

Generally, no. `takePersistableUriPermission()` is for Storage Access Framework `Uri` values, as in your `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` scenario. It is not for arbitrary `Uri` values, like you might get via `ACTION_PICK`, or `EXTRA_STREAM` on receiving `ACTION_SEND`, or the `Uri` passed to `ACTION_VIEW`, etc.

For `ACTION_SEND`, `ACTION_VIEW`, etc., you need to assume that your app has only transitory access to the content. You would need to have some sort of "import" operation and make your own copy of that content if you need longer-term access.

Comment: Yes, I expected as much, thank you